# Conditional update sql query error

Tags: sql

```
update contentpagenav
set active = case
                when active = 0 then active = 1
                when active = 1 then active = 0
         end
```

I get the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: **WHAT** database, version, edition ?????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to re-assign active in your then, the "set active =" is doing that.

```
   update contentpagenav
       set active =   case
                when active = 0 then 1
                when active = 1 then 0
                    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to do this is not with a case:

```
UPDATE contentpagenav SET active = 1-active;
```

If you're simplifying your question (you NEED to use CASE for some reason):

```
UPDATE contentpagenav SET active = CASE active
     WHEN 1 THEN 0 
     ELSE THEN 1
END;
```

If more than 2 possible values for active:

```
UPDATE contentpagenav SET active = CASE active
     WHEN 1 THEN 0
     WHEN 0 THEN 1
     WHEN 2 THEN ...
     ELSE ...
END;
```

Comment: -1 for a not very clear answer, hard to work out what you are explaining.

Comment: not to get snarky, but I didn't think that 4 words would be a challenge.  Assuming the only values he has are 0 and 1, this takes 1 and turns it into a 0 (1-1=0) and a 0 into a 1 (1-0=1).  If he has other values, he can throw a WHERE clause in to restrict this to <2 or explicitly 0 or 1.  As I understand it, CASE statements are slow, so where it's simpler to avoid them, you should.  Sorry for not codeblocking the other two...I plead ignorance of how to set up the blocks properly here.  A preview button would be nice.

Comment: I presume you wanted caps and multi-line codeblocks.  I think those are both annoying:P  especially multi-line code, which is not easily edited in a linux command-line SQL interface;)  In any case, fixed above